# i want to check if the URL is vaisited then it go through

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
 <a href="{{URL::to('/select_product')}}">Select a Product First</a>      </td>
  <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">&nbsp;</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td colspan="3" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
     
    @if(request()->is('/select_product'))
    <?php
      $product_image=DB::table('product_images')->where('product_id',$product_id)->first();
    ?>
    <img src="{!! asset('image/product/'.$product_image->image) !!}" width="60" height="70">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>{{$product_name}}&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>Price : Tk. {{$product_price}}. <br>Point : {5}<input name="spro" type="hidden" value="37" required="required"><input name="sprop" type="hidden" value="1000"><input name="pro_point" type="hidden" value="5">   </td>
  <input name="spro" type="text" value=""  placeholder="Select a Product First" class="s9" maxlength="0">     </td>
</tr>
@endif
```

in the if condition i want to do this work if the url site visit then it will go through the condition other wise it don't do anything but in my code it doesn't work

Comment: Are you storing any data in local-storage or in cookies for returning user/visited url ?

Comment: that's not the issue .I just want to check the URL is selected or visited

Comment: You aren't communicating your issue clearly. I am not sure what "I just want to check the URL is selected or visited" means.

Comment: Ok, I think I see, you are stating that @if(request()->is('/select_product')) is not evaluating to true even when you are visiting /select_product?

Comment: here @if(request()->is('/select_product'))      '/select_product              is a URL link. I just want that if this URL click/check/select      then it go through the  condition

Comment: yes you get this @KurtFriars

Answer (score 0):

Unless the path is exactly select-product, you should be using a wildcard like so:

```
    @if(request()->is('/select_product/*'))
```

or

```
    @if(request()->is('*/select_product/*'))
```

Comment: Can you {{ dd(request()->path()) }} right above the @if statement

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the route a name and in the blade check with :

```
<a href="{{URL::to('/select_product')}}">Select a Product First</a>      </td>
  <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">&nbsp;</td>
  <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td colspan="3" align="left" valign="middle" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
     
    
@if(request()->route()->getName() == "Route name")
    <?php
      $product_image=DB::table('product_images')->where('product_id',$product_id)->first();
    ?>
    <img src="{!! asset('image/product/'.$product_image->image) !!}" width="60" height="70">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>{{$product_name}}&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>Price : Tk. {{$product_price}}. <br>Point : {5}<input name="spro" type="hidden" value="37" required="required"><input name="sprop" type="hidden" value="1000"><input name="pro_point" type="hidden" value="5">   </td>
  <input name="spro" type="text" value=""  placeholder="Select a Product First" class="s9" maxlength="0">     </td>
</tr>
@endif
```

I mean in the web.php, if you do something like

```
Route::get('/select_product',function(){
...
})->name('Route name');
```